# Dynamic Sheet Name in Query in Google Spreashsheet

Tags: google-api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

In Google spreadsheet I want to query data in another sheet but the problem is that the name of sheet is present in a cell. So is there a way in QUERY function to dynamically mention sheet name. Basically I am trying to do something like this but with dynamic sheet name:

`=QUERY('2012'!A2:F;"select C, sum(F) where A='December' group by C order by sum(F) desc")`

I tried to do this but I get Parse Error:

```
=QUERY(INDIRECT("Overview!L5")!A2:F;"select C, sum(F) where A='December' group by C order by sum(F) desc")
```

In which Overview!L5 is the cell with sheet name to query. I also tried to concatenate quotes around INDIRECT but that didnt work either.

I think it is quite evident what I am trying to do from the query i.e. get sum of values in cells grouped by values in other cells.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

the INDIRECT looks to be the problem.
Try like this:

```
=query(INDIRECT(A1&"!A5:A10"),"select Col1")
```

i.e. if Cell A1 contains "food" the above is the same as:

```
=query(food!A5:A10,"select A")
```

and the same as:

```
=query(INDIRECT("food!A5:A10"),"select *")
```

**Note: the indirect uses "Col1" etc and not "A" because it does not pass the col letters.

Also ... The google groups forum might be a good place to look for spreadsheet formula answers.   productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/docs/spreadsheets

Comment: thanks for your reply! There is a problem with your code is that in my case name of the sheet is present in a cell (L5) but you have assumed it to be Food. Basically I am getting name of the sheet using INDIRECT("Overview!L5").

Comment: try this: =QUERY(INDIRECT(Overview!L5&"!A2:F");"select C, sum(F) where A='December' group by C order by sum(F) desc")   INDIRECT takes a string and returns a range.

Comment: Now I am getting this error: error: Invalid query: Column [F] does not exist in table. 

=INDIRECT(L5&"!A2:G") is returning value in A2 only.

Comment: "select Col3, sum(Col6) where Col1='December' group by Col3 order by sum(Col6) desc"  --- looks like it is not passing column letters, so use "Col1" instead of "A" etc.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to use dynamic structures in a query is to not include functions inside query but prepare strings in separate cells, for instance A1 for address B1 for arguments and then just QUERY(A1;B1)