# Use a sheet name based on Column Value

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-finance

Using Google Sheets or Excel:

I have columns (B) with Stock symbols, e.g.: B2=GOOG, B3=AAPL, B4= MSFT

I have Sheets named with these same stock symbols respectively. Eg: Sheet2: GOOG, Sheet3: AAPL, etc

I have a formula on Sheet1 that does some computation using data in other sheets. Eg: `K2=((GOOG!B2+GOOG!B5)/GOOG!B24)`

----I want to automate grabbing the correct sheet name based on column B without manually typing in the sheet name into this formula.----

Is there a way to input the sheet name in this formula `K2=((GOOG!B2+GOOG!B5)/GOOG!B24)` based on column B in sheet1?

Conceptually something like `K2=((*indirectB2*!B2+*indirectB2*!B5)/*indirectB2*!B24)`

In other words, how does one input a sheet name into a formula based on a string in a column

My example image is a tad different than mentioned above but same idea:

[image]

Comment: You should use the INDIRECT function - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850828/dynamic-sheet-name-in-query-in-google-spreashsheet

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using `=INDIRECT("'"&B4&"'!$B$2")+INDIRECT("'"&B4&"'!$B$5"))/INDIRECT("'"&B4&"'!$B$24")`

Answer (score 0):

Would `K4=((B4&!C43+B4&!B5)/B4&!B24)` work?